# How can I easily format the date fields of my GQLQuery to another Timezone?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, timezone, pytz

[Edit] And, I should add, most elegantly? I guess (but not sure how) I could just loop through the results in the python code first and format each date there, but I'd rather only loop once...[\Edit]

In my case British Summer Time (which has just recently kicked in).

At the moment my topmost directly formated date is correct, but the dates in the individual rows of the result are still in UTC (1 hour behind). Example output is a templated page that looks like this (where UTC as returned by `datetime.now` in this case is 12:42):

> Time is now: 13:42 on 05 April, 2012
>
> 2012-04-05 13:10:00   Event 234
>
> 2012-04-05 13:10:00   Event 235
>
> 2012-04-05 13:10:00   Event 236
>
> ...

Here's what I'm doing...

```
from pytz.gae import pytz  # N.B. Using the recommended version of pytz
from datetime import datetime

# Use datetime now (in UTC) to select upcoming events (also stored in UTC)

nowat = datetime.now()
upcoming_events = db.GqlQuery(
  "SELECT * FROM Event WHERE eventdatetime >= :1",nowat)

# Convert time to BST and print to string…

utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
nowat = utc.localize(nowat)
bst = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
timenow = nowat.astimezone(bst).strftime("%H:%M on %d %B, %Y")

# Pass results to template for formating… (this is the Django engine)

template_values = {
        'time' : timenow,
        'events' : upcoming_events
 }
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'html','today.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path,template_values))
```

I thought there might be some magic I could similarly apply in the templating code - but it only seems that the `date` [built-in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) allows formating of the datetime NOT conversion from UTC.

Template is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Time is now: {{ time }}</p>
    <table>
      {% for event in events %} 
        <tr>
          <td> {{ event.eventdatetime }} </td>
          <td> {{ event.name }} </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}  
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with django's template engine, you can use [Time zone aware output in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates)

example usage from the documentation:

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}

{% timezone None %}
    Server time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

Comment: That looks excellent - but unfortunately I tried it and got this: `TemplateSyntaxError: 'tz' is not a valid tag library: Could not load template library from django.templatetags.tz, No module named tz` - so I'm not sure what modules GAE provides...

Comment: if it's not included, you could take the django source code for that tag and stick it into your own template tags, as described here: http://4.flowsnake.org/archives/459

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Bit of a pain to break out the 'tz' tag code.

Comment: I'm getting the same TemplateSyntaxError in GAE. Unfortunately the link doesn't work anymore and I can't find any resource that explains how to do this. Would you be able to explain, or refer me to a resource that explains, how to add the tz module?